# Only update rows where Maturity Dates greater than python max date - 2261 - cannot convert float NaN to integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking to update any dates greater than Python's max date:

```
display(df['maturity_date'].dtypes)

dtype('O')

display(df['maturity_date'].describe())

count                    3488
unique                    766
top       2166-09-23 00:00:00
freq                      130
Name: maturity_date, dtype: object


m = df['maturity_date'].str[:4].astype(int) > 2261

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

In this case there appears to be none so is this the reason the error is raised? How can I change so Pandas only updates if the condition is true? Best to  suppress the error or handle it?

```
df['maturity_date'] = df['maturity_date'].mask(m, '2261' + df['maturity_date'].str[4:]) # for all dates greater than python max date replace
df['maturity_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['maturity_date'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need convert to `float`, because missing `NaN`s or `None`s values have type `float` because  in pandas is impossible convert `NaN`s to `int` per design:

```
m = df['maturity_date'].str[:4].astype(float) > 2261
```

Another solution is remove rows with `NaN`s or `None`s first:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['maturity_date'])
```

For check problematic rows use:

```
df = df[df['maturity_date'].isnull()]
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. Works now!

Comment: @PeterLucas - Super, glad can help!